# Furnace ignition intermittent?

Tags: hvac, furnace

Well, here is another question related to my OLD carrier furnace. Again, it is a 58DXA060-101GG (or 100GG.) The issue is that during the day it seems to do pretty ok as far is starting a heating cycle. At night/early morning it seems to be a different story. The thermostat will call for heat, the inducer motor will start up. After a pre-determined time (1 minute?) it shuts off. The thermostat is still calling for heat. If I power cycle the system either from the thermostat or the circuit breaker, or furnace blower door switch, it will run the cycle again and 9 out of 10 times it will continue as normal. Sometimes during the day/evening it will do this as well. But usually we wake up to a house, set to 68-72, and it is 62-66.

I have replaced the pilot once before (3-wire spark pilot), and it still had the issue. I replaced the ignition lockout control, still same issue. These 2 items were "diagnosed" as issues by an HVAC repair person. Obviously they were not the solution. I can't make the furnace replicate the issue, because when I power cycle to test the furnace, it "resets" and works fine. If I don't power cycle, the furnace stays in lockout and I can't take any readings.

I really don't want to throw money replacing parts in hopes it fixes it. My next parts on the list of possible problems are the main control board and the gas valve. I have read similar issues on other sites that people replaced the main control boards and that solved the problem. The furnace is so old that it doesn't have and LED or other indicator to show an error code. So that option is out. Also no flame sensor in this furnace as the 3-wire pilot is a b-metal switch that acts as a flame sensor. Any suggestions?

My plan was to buy the control board next. It looks like the new replacement versions have LED lights, which could help in the future.

Other observations include:
     Spark igniter will spark for an extended period of time sometimes.
     Pilot light will sometimes "sputter" and the igniter will spark again to re-light.

Comment: I also forgot to mention...last weekend the furnace decided to do nothing at all. I could get the relay to click on the main board when I pressed the door switch and let it out. But nothing more than the relay clicking. This has also lead me to believe the main board could be an issue.

Comment: FWIW: I had similar problems on my old Lennox which were diagnosed by the HVAC company to be the ignitor module.  I have two dead ones now.   The last time, the tech said that they will not replace the OEM Johnson Controls anymore, but the generic Honeywell replacement is more reilable.  The box says: S8610U 1003  Universal Replacement Intermittent pilot Module.

Comment: My Carrier gas furnace is now 25 years old and working fine. About 3 or 4 years ago the furnace would not work. The heating and ac repair service  that I use said it was the control board and I authorized replacement. That fixed the problem. Maybe 5 years before that the hot surface igniter wouldn't glow and so wouldn't ignite the gas. A new igniter fixed that.

Comment: @JeffCates Does the pilot light when the furnace doesn't work, or does the igniter just continually spark until the unit shuts down?

Comment: When it sparks, it eventually will light. Once it lights, the furnace continues as normal. It seems to be an issue with it being cold. The AC unit works just fine in the summer, so the control board working the main blower works, but may not be working right for the furnace side.

Comment: When it doesn't work, I don't know what all it does, other than hear the inducer run. Its so random that we never know when it will or won't run normal. I plan to replace the control board and see if that helps. I also have another new pilot and new igniter, even though those were replaced last year.

Comment: My chore this weekend is to replace the main control board. Next weekend I should have a new pressure switch to install. If these items don't solve the issue, then the other items on the repair list are the inducer board and the gas valve. BTW, after further investigation, this seems to be a 90% or 95% efficiency furnace, so fixing would be better than replacing unless the cost out weights the benefit.

Comment: I have replaced the blower control board (ICM275), the pressure switch and the inducer control board, yesterday. All suspected items on the list of what could be wrong. However the furnace was again not functioning this morning, and again at some point this afternoon. I did notice that the ICM275 LED is not a diagnostic LED but just to prove there is 24v, but it seems to flash very dim and sometimes looks like it misses a pulse...I have since ordered a new 120v-24v transformer and a gas valve.

Comment: After these 2 items, all that will be left is the ILO which was replaced 2 years ago and I can't believe it is bad. It sparks nice and strong when it does. So its got to be something else. When I unplugged it and checked it out, no burnt traces, no rust or water penetration. I have cleaned all the tubes out and checked for plugged ports and found everything to be clean. I even drained the condensate system, as it had a little gunk in it.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the problem was? I have the exact same issue with our 25 year old furnace. I've replaced the flame sensor. The HSI is lighting after the inducer starts. I assume the HSI is good, because it heats up and allows the gas valve to open and give gas, then lights and flame sensor does job of recognizing flame. I have exact issue. The furnace doesn't relight during night or early morning. I'm almost ready to give in...and call for help. Thanks for any help.
Sorry, I know this isn't an answer, but it wouldn't let me comment because I'm don't have the proper rating. I didn'

Comment: Nope, not yet. Still battling with it. I know it's just a matter of time before it'll need to be completely replaced. But throwing several grand into an HVAC system is a bit more out of my budget than a few parts here and there. I have new hi-limit switches to install just because that's about all that's left besides wiring..lol. I'd say, in the last 30 days, it's maybe failed on average once every 5-7 days. Not horrible, but not fun when it seems to do it during the night, or when we are out of the house for a few hours.

Comment: So, I did some more researching, it looks like I,need to check out the entire condensate drain setup. I have cleaned it out before, but reading a lot of other places with furnaces doing the same thing....appears it could be a starting place. I might just replace my trap hoses and clean it out really good and see how it runs.

Comment: Still haven't figured this thing out. Im running some tests this week. Tonight I bypassed half the condensate trap, running a tube from the collector box into a bucket, the other side from inducer motor to trap still. If I can get the furnace to function for the week, without intervention, then I can probably call the condensate trap my issue. Of it last a day or two, I'll likely pull the other drain from the trap and run it to the bucket for testing. But all I can think of that's left is this trap. A new trap isn't a lot of money, actually after the few hundred replacing parts over the.....

Comment: ....years, a $30 trap is nothing, and would be a shame to have that be my problem all along. If that's the case, the HVAC techs at 2 local places need some more troubleshooting training. Ill keep posting what I find.

Comment: Well, that didn't do the trick. Bypassing the trap and a day and half later, the furnace did its thing of not wanting to operate. Back to square one. The trap was cleaned out  and re-installed. So we will see how long till the next time it doesn't want to work.